# Base 64 back to original string?

Tags: php

Im base 64 encoding a string to use as a URL param.

I know base 64 can use characters such as '/' which do not play well with URLs so:

```
$encoded = base64_encode($value);
return str_replace(array('+', '=', '/'), array('-', '_', '~'), $encoded);
```

I was just wondering, how can I get the encoded base 64 string (with the replaced chars) back to it's original form?

Comment: Try to replace it back and decode.

Comment: Just execute each transformation step in reverse order.

Comment: Why not just URL en-/decode?

Comment: So whats the advantage of URL encode/decode over my method?

Comment: @hek2mgl Why do you think this is irreversible?

Comment: @panthro [URL encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) will make sure all characters will work well as part of a URL (hence the name) and it will "always" work, as well as provide a *standard* encoding rather than your own invention. So you could just do `url-encode(base64-encode(value))` and then put it in a URL, and then you, or someone else, can do `base64-decode(url-decode(value))` to do the reverse. In short: You have a problem and URL encoding solves that problem, and it's the de-facto standard way of doing it.

Comment: @Gumbo Srry, I was wrong. I admitted that already below Everts answer

Answer (score 1):

Yes that will totally work. And you can actually drop the equals (`=`) usually entirely :)

To do this, just do the exact opposite `str_replace()` function with the first two arguments reversed.

Comment: @hek2mgl: what makes you say that? base64 encoding only uses the alphabet (upper and lower case), numbers and `+` and `/`. Totaling 26 + 26 + 10 + 2 = 64 characters. The equals sign is padding and most decoders can live without it.

Comment: hey! you are right (when OP removes the `=` transformation, as you suggested) +1.. Srry. missed that!

Comment: So do I need to remove the = sign for this to work? Or will it work if I still keep it in the replace? (I would rather keep it in)

Comment: @panthro: No you can also replace the equals signs like you did. They are kinda pointless though so there's really no difference if you remove them.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Biffen, take a look at [`urlencode`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.urlencode.php) and [`urldecode`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.urldecode.php)

If you realy want to do it, you need to restore first your value to the original one, and then decode

```
$value = str_replace(array('-', '_', '~'), array('+', '=', '/'), $value);
return base64_decode($value);
```

Comment: Thanks, what are the advantages of URL encode over this?